# Can't clone repository SourceTree. No port number support?

Tags: ubuntu, git, ubuntu-14.04

I have an ubuntu web server that is accessible by an IP + port 27003.
I also installed git.
I do not have a `domainname.tld`, just the ip and port 27003 instead of 80.

When I do `git remote add origin http://[ip]:27003/mytest.git` everything seems ok.

When I want to clone my repository with SourceTree and I add `http://[ip]:27003/mytest.git` to 'Source URL', SourceTree tells me: `This is not a valid source path / URL`.

Is my URL wrong, does SourceTree not support port numbers or is it something else?

Comment: Clicking on the "this is not a valid URL text" will give more information about the failure. Also, just doing `git remote add` will not check if the connection actually works, so this command succeeding is in no way an indication that your configuration works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add config ssh at `~/.ssh/config`
Some thing like this

```
Host yourhost
   user youruser
   hostname your.ip.xx.xx
   RSAAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourfile.pem
   Port yourport
```

Then add use it normaly

`git remote add origin https://yourhost/mytest.git`